# Bing Map Route Service - What is the Route Result Summary Distance unit? How to change it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I've been looking around but I have not found an answer, so...

Does anyone know in which unit (miles or km) the Bing Map Route Service returns Result Summary Distance in? And is there a way to change that unit?

In other words:

```
e.Result.Result.Summary.Distance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in the request:

```
request.UserProfile = new UserProfile { DistanceUnit = DistanceUnit.Kilometer };
```

The `Result.Summary.Distance` will then be in this unit. [Kilometer is default.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967514.aspx)